# Why is this XSS, according to Brakeman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

Can someone explain to me why this is a security problem?

```
= link_to new_locale.to_s, params.slice(:id, :reader_id, :screen_type).merge(locale: new_locale)
```

I am trying to add a simple partial to my project to be able to switch between languages.  I don't really want this partial to have to interact with each controller or switch the user to a different page or have to know all possible valid parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick pass over the source and I suspect one of the following is triggering it:

1. You're calling `.to_s` for the first argument to `link_to`, resulting in an `html_safe` string being passed in.
2. User input being handed directly to `link_to`, which I believe would be a false positive.

You can dig in further by checking out [the source for the `link_to` XSS tests in Brakeman](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman/blob/master/lib/brakeman/checks/check_link_to.rb) yourself.